# How can I enable SSL / HTTPS on a NextCloud instance self-hosted with Docker on my home server (Pop!_OS / Ubuntu)?

Tags: docker, apache, ubuntu, self-hosting, nextcloud

I have installed Docker and used it to build a container for this official [NextCloud Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud).

I was able to install NextCloud and serve it on localhost:8080. However, I want to serve this NextCloud instance externally so I can access it from outside of my home network. In order to do that I need to enable HTTPS. As far as I can tell the Docker Image is using an apache server.

**How can I enable this container/app to use HTTPS so I can access it externally?**

Here is a screenshot of NextCloud running on localhost:8080 open to its "Administration > Overview" page in which it shows me security warnings including the need for HTTPS:
[image]

Comment: You either put a proxy server in front of that application container (so a separate http server, probably lighttpd or nginx) which terminates the ssl encryption and internally uses the application container as resource, or you need to alter the container setup such that it includes a valid ssl certificate.